# What is faster to use: Arrray.includes or swicth case (in node.js)?

Tags: arrays, node.js, switch-statement

**Background:**

I have a case where I need to validate a variable and it can be in one of two arrays of valid items. Each of these arrays has a fairly small number of items.

the two approaches I thought of were to either use the `includes` function on each array or use `switch/case`.

It seemed that the `includes` option was cleaner than the `switch/case` since I wouldn't have to manually mention each `case`.

**IMHO: It would also be more correct from the code management perspective**

**Question:**

Given values in arrays, what is **faster** to use: `includes` or `switch/case`?

Answer (score -2):

`switch/case` is faster. It runs about 2.5 times faster.

I ran some code using `moment` to time things.
The print outs were implemented to see that it runs correctly, but during the timing step I commented them out.

I checked for items in the first array, in the second and in no array at all.
Each version ran 10,000,000 and results are in milliSeconds.
This ran on a MacBook Pro, 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7 CPU, 16 GB RAM.

**Code:**

```
const moment = require('moment')

const firstItems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const secondItems = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
const testingItems = [1, 6, 10, 11]

const printHere = (here, item) => {
  console.log(`Found it in ${here}: ${item}`)
}

const printNotHere = (item) => {
  console.log(`Could not find it: ${item}`)
}

const printTiming = (start, end) => {
  console.log(`This took: ${end - start}`)
}
const timesToRun = 10000000

const runIncludes = () => {
  testingItems.map(testItem => {
    if (firstItems.includes(testItem)) {
      // printHere('first', testItem)
      return
    }

    if (secondItems.includes(testItem)) {
      // printHere('second', testItem)
      return
    }

    // printNotHere(testItem)
  })
}

const runSwitchCase = () => {
  testingItems.map(testItem => {
    switch (testItem) {
      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3:
      case 4:
      case 5:
        // printHere('first', testItem)
        break

      case 6:
      case 7:
      case 8:
      case 9:
      case 10:
        // printHere('second', testItem)
        break

      default:
        // printNotHere(testItem)
        break
    }
  })
}

console.log('Running includes')
const includesMomentStart = moment()
for (var i = 0; i < timesToRun; i++) {
  runIncludes()
}
printTiming(includesMomentStart, moment())

console.log('Running switch cases')    
const switchCaseMomentStart = moment()
for (var j = 0; j < timesToRun; j++) {
  runSwitchCase()
}
printTiming(switchCaseMomentStart, moment())
```

The results (averaged out on three runs) were:

```
Running includes
This took: 2503
Running switch cases
This took: 1082
```